# Using MySQL like for Column name

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement, sql-like

I want to write a mysql select query using preparedstatement. But theres syntax error at the last part which is `concat('%', itemName, '%')";` `itemName` is a column of table `ItemMain`. 
I already tried 3 queries given below.

```
String sql ="SELECT * FROM ItemMain WHERE ? = 'All' OR ? like concat('%', itemName, '%')";
String sql ="SELECT * FROM ItemMain WHERE ? = 'All' OR ? like  '%'+itemName+'%'";
String sql ="SELECT * FROM ItemMain WHERE ? = 'All' OR ? like  '%itemName%'";
```

Comment: What application language is this written in?

Comment: sorry. I couldnt mention. Written in Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although @Marc B is absolutely right (+1) I would like to add something. I believe that your have a real task where you *need* such functionality, so I would like to suggest you the following solution.

You can create query dynamically as following. If you are using plain JDBC you can run query like `desc YOUR_TABLE_NAME`. It will return a easy-to-parse list of fields in your table. You can implement your "like" statement yourself either using regular expression or simple string manipulation methods as `startsWith("xyz")` instead of `like 'xyz%'`, `endsWith("xyz")` instead of `like '%xyz'` and `contains("xyz")` instead of `like '%xyz%'`. Now you can create SQL statement dynamically by adding fields the meet your requirements.

Comment: Thanx for grate help @AlexR. Seems I have to use regular expressions in that case.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use placeholders for field names. The queries would have to be

```
... WHERE somefield=? OR otherfield LIKE concat('%', ?, '%')
```

placeholders are for **VALUES** only. field/table names, function namesm or any of the "Structural" words in SQL are offlimits.

This is a general rule for mysql prepared statements. It is not a java/php/c#/whatever restriction.

Comment: @ Marc B do you mean i can not use Like against column name? How can i compare against column name using like within mysql query. If I used where it gives only exact match?

Comment: you can use as many columns in a like as you want. you just can't specify them using placeholders.

Comment: Found the answer to my problem.

     String sql ="SELECT * FROM ItemMain WHERE ? = 'All' OR itemName like '%"+keyword+"%'";
            Object []values ={keyword};
            ResultSet res = DBHandller.getData(sql, conn, values);

I swapped the column name, keyword and change the syntax here '%"+keyword+"%'";
Now it works fine. thnx all.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my problem.

```
 String sql ="SELECT * FROM ItemMain WHERE ? = 'All' OR itemName like '%"+keyword+"%'";
        Object []values ={keyword};
        ResultSet res = DBHandller.getData(sql, conn, values);
```

I swapped the column name, keyword and change the syntax here '%"+keyword+"%'";
Now it works fine. thnx al